# Having trouble requiring local module

Tags: node.js

I am using a file structure similar to this:

```
-Projects
    -a
        -package.json
        -lib
            -index.js
    -b
        -package.json
        -lib
            -index.js
```

---

The `package.json` file within both `a` and `b` contains:

```
"main": "lib"
```

Within the `a` index.js file, I am trying to use:

```
var b = require('../b');
```

and getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../b'
```

---

Am I completely wrong in trying to require it this way? What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to require the module with a path, it will search for that file and not a module. what you want is, in the package.json of `a` is this

```
"dependencies": {
   "b": "file:../b"
}
```

then in `a` index.js you can call it this way
`var b = require('b');`

Comment: Awesome, got it. Didn't realize I needed to `npm install` it as well, but makes sense since it needs to grab the dependencies. Thanks for your help!